# What is Kirito's relationship with the girls of SAO?

Tags: sword-art-online

In the first and second seasons of SAO, Kirito seemed to be interested in more than one girl at the same time. At the end they are all friends and such, but they are all jealous of him and he likes them back and all.

Some would argue Asuna is the real girlfriend, but:

- In the cave with Sinon (SAO II, ep.11, 20:30), Sinon asks "Is there someone you don't want seeing this?" Kirito shyly answers no.
- While introducing Asuna to Sinon, Kirito only said that Rika and Asuna were his friends. Asuna looked okay, a bit like she was thinking "Yeah I'm just his friend."

These two occasions got me wondering: is he playing them all at the same time or something?

What I'm asking for is something like a timeline, which shows when Kirito likes whom.

Comment: Well if you have also read the gaiden, which is one of the extras in the sao light novel series, it shows a spoiler for later about how the girls (ALL of them) have accepted that they can't be with Kirito unless Asuna allows it. So they get together (including Asuna) and all decide to use the machine from alicization (I can't remember the name) and spend the equivalent of four years married to Kirito together with him.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In light novel Volume 5 and Volume 6 - *Phantom Bullet*, it is confirmed that Kirito is going out with Asuna.

1. From *Volume 5 - Chapter 1*, when Kirito went to meet Kikuoka from the Ministry of Internal Affairs' Virtual Division for a talk regarding victims of Death Gun in GGO (emphasis mine):

   > “...Well, at least I’m together with **my girlfriend**.”
   >
   > “I see, I am jealous to death over that one point, Kirito-kun. The next time we’re in ALO, wouldn’t you introduce me to some girls? Take the Sylph Lord for example, she is just my type.”

   This conversation took place before they began talking about the cases related to GGO (B-part of episode 1, SAO II), and was cut off from the anime.
2. From *Volume 5 - Chapter 2*, after the meeting with Kikuoka, he met up with Asuna at the Imperial Palace for their date (emphasis mine):

   > “...Oh yes, why did you choose the Imperial Palace **for our date**? Kirito-kun, are you interested in history?”
   >
   > “Well, not really. The main reason was... recently, I was called around here for some stupid business...”

   This conversation took place before Kirito's talk about the closed network of the surveillance system in Imperial Palace (A-part of episode 1, SAO II), and was also cut off from the anime.
3. From *Volume 6 - Chapter 9*, before the final round of BoB (emphasis mine):

   > I really won’t dare to say this to a real person in the real world. **No, considering that I already have a girlfriend in Asuna**, it’s unforgivable even in the virtual world. However, I dare to swear to god that this isn’t about trying to get a date in the VR world, but to fulfill my duty and mission, and also a necessary step to ensure Sinon’s own safety.

   This inner monologue took place when Kirito asked Shinon to explain the format of the final round of BoB, which took place between 30 players on a huge map (anime episode 8, SAO II).

   *I think this should be enough to show that Kirito and Asuna are dating in real life after the events in Aincrad and ALO.*

Comment: Good answer; well cited. To augment this answer, perhaps Asuna recognizes that Kirito simply interacts well with other girls, that he's attractive to other girls, and seems to trust Kirito instead of getting jealous.

Answer (score 1):

In volume 1, Kirito and Asuna is the clear cut pairing to any reader, as there are no mentions of other girls in Kirito's life except mentioning that he has a sister, without going into detail about her. As nhahtdh explains in [his answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/19403/17758), it is very clear that Asuna is the main heroine of the story, and that Kirito is committed to her.

So why are there so many other girls involved with Kirito?

Starting in volume 2, Silica, Lisbeth, Yui, and Sachi, were all side characters introduced to give readers the same feelings that the author, Reki Kawahara, felt when he played MMOs. As with most MMO players, he was never part of one of the top groups, and had great respect for players that could clear the hardest content or had the best items. This sense of awe that was instilled in him in games is the same feeling that he wanted to portray by showing some weaker characters and their struggles and then having a hero show up and really show them how *badass* someone end-game could be.

Kawahara notes at the end of the volume 2:

> I have previously also played some online games. But no matter in what
>   game, I have never been part of a high-ranking group. I merely envied those
>   eternally strong players with the best equipment and reputation, one after
>   another easily defeating monsters, and afterwards feeling that they were "So skilled! So strong!" (haha)
>   Therefore, I wanted to write about not only the volume one's protagonists
>   Kirito and Asuna and their  type of top players, but wanted
>   even more to write something about the stories of ordinary mid-level
>   players; and this second volume's four short stories, have precisely this kind
>   of content. Regardless of which story, they are basically about Kirito
>   debuting and causing a big stir; and feeling that he is "So skilled! So
>   strong!" like Scilica and Lizbet felt, is precisely what I have felt every year
>   since becoming an MMO player. Really, and once would be enough, I
>   really want to know what it feels like to show off to others a weapon of
>   which there are only three copies in the entire server.

Kawahara created many side stories which introduced these different female characters, all of which had their own backstories and troubles to be solved.

However, despite creating these girls and their problems, he always has one solution to their problems: Kirito. Since Kirito is the main protagonist of the story, Kirito was always the hero which would show up to fill this role of legendary MMO player. Kirito is the game's hero and all of the focus and glory shines on him and his perspective.

Additional comments on this matter by Kawahara in volume 2 Author Notes:

> Besides that, there's one more thing that I must apologize to everyone about.
>   Even though the four female characters in this book are all different female
>   players, their male counterpart, as discussed earlier, was always Kirito-san.
>   Even though there is no way for me to explain myself to everyone properly
>   on this point, I painfully excuse myself, and ask that everyone please use
>   the "even though the criminal and victim change every time, the detective is
>   always the same person" mindset you have when reading detective novel
>   series... you can't do it right? Sorry, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since the release of *Sword Art Online: Ordinal Scale* (the recent movie addition to the series) it is safe to say the Kirito and Asuna are in a proper relationship,

> perhaps even engaged (I'm not sure of the significance of giving a ring)in Japanese culture.

He maintains his friendship with the other females in the series as per usual.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to when Sinon asked Kirito " Is there someone you don't want seeing this?" and then Kirito replying "no" when they were in the cave during Bullet Of Bullets 3. He probably said "no" because he didn't what her to feel embarrassed because she was on top of him sexually(unintentionally). And he probably referred Asuna as "a friend" because of the same reason.

Comment: You're saying "probably". Can you provide any evidence to back it up?