# In SAO 2 did Asuna break up with Kirito?

Tags: culture, sword-art-online

I noticed that when introducing Shino to Asuna and Lisbeth, Kirito mentioned them as his *nakama*. Why is that? Why is it that Kirito didn't introduce Asuna as his girlfriend? Is this what is normally done by a Japanese couple? Or did they broke up?

Comment: [Related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19399/kirito-and-his-girlfriend-relationships)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no reason to think so. When Kirito introduced Shino to Asuna and Liz at the Dicey Cafe, the three of them were preparing to bring Shino back to her hometown, where she encountered the gunman she shot and killed as a young child, so that she could accept the consequences of her actions and overcome her guilt of having killed a man. One typically doesn't revisit the scene of a childhood trauma with just anyone, so Kirito, whom Shino already knew and trusted through GGO, called Asuna and Liz his *nakama* to tell Shino that he trusted them -- therefore she should too. It was more important to convey that Asuna and Liz were trustworthy rather than the fact that Asuna was his girlfriend.

Comment: Wouldn't Asuna be more trustworthy if she is his girlfriend, rather than his nakama?

Comment: Shino wouldn't have viewed it that way, seeing as she was an outsider to their relationship and knew nothing of how it came to be. If all she knew was that they were going out, she might have simply seen Asuna as an admirer or perhaps someone with ill intent. The alternative makes it clear that they've been through a lot together.
Kirito may have also had other reasons, being the player that he is.

Comment: `the three of them were preparing to bring Shino back to her hometown, where she encountered the gunman she shot and killed as a young child,` I think in this scene, they were going to let Shino meet the lady she saved in the past? I'm not disagreeing that this would dig up her trauma, though.

Comment: Yeah, her and the baby she was pregnant with at the time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the cultural reasoning behind it, but I can at least say, from a story point of view, they have not broken up, since

> Later in the story, Asuna and Kirito walk to Asuna's house so Kirito can properly greet Asuna's parents, which is not something you would do when you've broken up :P

That's about as non-spoilery I can get, but I hope it helps as an answer...

Comment: nice, avoided a very spoilery part there

Answer (score 0):

You guys are over thinking it. Remember when asuna was trapped in the game, how kirito went crazy trying to get her back. How in the all the show their friends call them lovebirds, cause of how they acted in public, or how spoiler if you haven't watch all of it. How when Yugi died and they were sitting on the grass kirito said to asuna "I don't know what's going to happen tomorrow, but what I do know is that want to be with you" might not be what he really said, but it's close, also shino called them lovebirds to.

Answer (score -1):

In both ALO and GGO it seems that Kirito shars feelings for sinon as much as she does him not to mention what happened in the cave but it seemed like they had a connection and in the Excalibur episode when sinon says when you draw this  think of me Asuna her face would turn in disappointment as Kirito said okay when I draw this I will think of you I'm also looking forward to them dating

Answer (score -2):

You guys are overthinking. Don't expect an anime to reach its full romance right off the bat.  Asuna loves Kirito, as she states that Kirito gave her a home to come to. And Kirito lives for Asuna, in the SAO arc remember how he poured his heart out to Asuna, saying that she is everything to him, that he lives for Asuna, and that they both will protect one another.

I really don't mind season 3 and 4,

> people saying Asuna won't be main character

she is already a main character, but the LN tell stories from Kirito's perspective, and he seems to be a trouble-sponge. In GGO Kirito said that he can't afford to die, he now has a reason to live, Asuna. If they were to finalize Kirito's and Asuna's wedding, the anime wouldn't have much drama anymore. I feel like their weeding should be saved for the last, and final episodes.

And I don't mind the new volumes, I just hope they still bring up their relationship in at least flashbacks or them missing one another, as those 2 are meant to be together.

> I heard something happens to Kirito after he comes back from UWO (season 3) and that Asuna goea to rescue her prince inside UWO (season 4).

Comment: Hi. It would be great if you could use paragraphs to format your answer; at the moment it is a barely readable wall of text. (Paragraph breaks are inserted by leaving an empty line.) Also, you can use spoiler markup by typing `>! ` (mind the space!) at the beginning of a paragraph; it will then be hidden from view.

Answer (score -2):

I mean if you watch the Excalibur episode towards the end it looks like krito has feelings for sinon as she says when you draw it think of me and if you look at asuna's face she looks disappointed and sad so they had to have broke up and I'm also looking forward to the Kirito x sinon

Answer (score -3):

In one episode, Shino was laying on Kirito's lap as he was staring at her butt. In this scene she asks if there's anyone out there that wouldn't want to see them like that. Kirito doesn't respond except with a nervous smile.

He also picked up Shino from her school as if he were her boyfriend. He didn't introduce Asuna as his girlfriend when Shino met her, he flirts with Shino in front of Asuna, and he treats Asuna as if she's not special, like he would a girlfriend. This makes it look like Kirito has moved on and Asuna is the one holding on to this relationship.

Comment: Could you mention which episodes these things happen in? That would make this answer a lot better. Please edit to add them in.