# In Sword Art Online, why do Kirito and Asuna never refer to each other as boyfriend and girlfriend?

Tags: sword-art-online

I'm relying entirely on the English Dubbed version. As far as I know, they only refer to each other as friends when speaking to other people. Is there an explanation as to why?

Comment: I don't recall them ever doing that in the Japanese voices either.

Comment: Related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19399/what-is-kiritos-relationship-with-the-girls-of-sao

Comment: Related, even possibly a duplicate, as it's not clear if you know of any "we're friends" moments other than the one detailed here: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20497/in-sao-2-did-asuna-break-up-with-kirito